# How do I get Windows 7 Explorer to respect the iOS rotate flag in photos and videos?

Tags: windows-7, video, photos, ios

When I copy the photos/videos off an iOS device onto my Windows box, some of them are upside down, when viewed in the Explorer.  I imagine that is because Explorer doesn't respect the *Rotate* flag in iOS devices

How can I get Windows to respect the Rotate flag?

P.S.  I am not interested in rotating them manually (as in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/564233/iphone-recorded-videos-getting-rotated-on-windows-systems) question) - I want them to show up correctly to begin with

Comment: The inbox JPEG decoder in Windows 7 does not respect the rotate flag. This feature was added in Windows 8 and should work out of the box.

For Windows 7, an alternative would be to install a third party WIC codec for handling JPEG. (Something like the FastPictureViewer codec perhaps?)