# Video orientation flag reset or disabling it on youtube

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, orientation

I've recorded a video on my smartphone (android-based).

I've been recording it in a landscape mode.

Then when I uploaded it on youtube - it somehow recognized the original orientation and made it to portrait mode.

I understand that I may use youtube editor feature and rotate it there - but I don't want to do that for 2 reasons:

1. It is another lossy conversion
2. The video in a wrong orientation is of a lower resolution - 720p, whereas the original video is 1080p.

So what I would like to know from community either:

- if it's possible to reset an orientation flag in the video (it was compressed using h264 in mkv with ffmpeg)
- or how to disable auto-rotating on youtube

?

PS: yep, I tried to google on both questions

Comment: Check my answer to the above linked question. You can reset the orientation flag with `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0`. (Edit: found a better duplicate, but this is also relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/564233/iphone-recorded-videos-getting-rotated-on-windows-systems)

Comment: @slhck: amazing. Upvoted there. But one more question: how would I see the current orientation of a given video? None of "meta" or "rota" or "s:" or ":v" substrings are in the video details.

Comment: With [`ffprobe`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) for example, using `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_streams input.mp4`, it would show `TAG:rotate=90`. Or [`mediainfo`](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), which would show `Rotation`. The MediaInfo GUI should show it as well, depending on how you like to work with data. Both solutions are cross-platform anyway.

Comment: @slhck: yep, mediainfo is the saver, thank you